# Parser trees comparison: Common sublist in two lists

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

My goal is to identify whether two sentences is duplicated.

I'm trying to compare the parser trees of the two sentences.
I have extract the tags from the parser trees in the following format

```html
['ROOT', 'SBARQ', 'WHADVP', 'WRB', 'SQ', 'VP', 'VBP', 'ADJP', 'RB', 'JJ', 'NP', 'NNP', 'NP', 'NP', 'NNS', 'VP', 'VBG', 'NP', 'NP', 'NNS', 'SBAR', 'WHNP', 'WDT', 'S', 'VP', 'VBP', 'ADVP', 'RB', 'VP', 'VBN', 'PP', 'IN', 'NP', 'NNP', '.']
['ROOT', 'SBARQ', 'WHADVP', 'WRB', 'SQ', 'VBP', 'NP', 'NNS', 'VP', 'VB', 'NP', 'NP', 'NNP', 'NNS', 'SBAR', 'WHNP', 'WDT', 'S', 'VP', 'MD', 'VP', 'VB', 'VP', 'VBN', 'ADVP', 'RB', 'PP', 'IN', 'NP', 'NNP', '.']
```

I want to get the length of common sublists of the two lists. In the above case, the results would be 4('ROOT', 'SBARQ', 'WHADVP', 'WRB')+5('SBAR', 'WHNP', 'WDT', 'S', 'VP')+2('ADVP', 'RB')+5('PP', 'IN', 'NP', 'NNP', '.').

Or do you have any other solutions can make use of the parse tree for the similarity of two sentences.
One more issue is, what is the fastest way to get the parse tree? Since I have more than 300,000 sentence pairs to compare...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are POS tags, not parse trees. Are you sure you are solving the right problem?

Comment: These are pos tags I got from parse trees. I thought the common sublist of pos tag lists would be useful...... Do you have some insights to share what I should do using the parse tree to decide whether the sentences are duplicated?

Comment: Since you are not simply comparing the sentences word for word, I don't know what you mean by "duplicated". For "duplicated with minor variations" I would do a word-level diff of the sentences. So no, I can't offer any suggestion. Edit your question to clarify what you mean, and maybe someone can suggest an approach.

Answer (score 1):

The python stdlib includes the `difflib` module for doing differences, something like this (though the results are a little different from what you expected):

```
pos1 = ['ROOT', 'SBARQ', 'WHADVP', 'WRB', 'SQ', 'VP', 'VBP', 'ADJP', 'RB', 'JJ', 'NP', 'NNP', 'NP', 'NP', 'NNS', 'VP', 'VBG', 'NP', 'NP', 'NNS', 'SBAR', 'WHNP', 'WDT', 'S', 'VP', 'VBP', 'ADVP', 'RB', 'VP', 'VBN', 'PP', 'IN', 'NP', 'NNP', '.']
pos2 = ['ROOT', 'SBARQ', 'WHADVP', 'WRB', 'SQ', 'VBP', 'NP', 'NNS', 'VP', 'VB', 'NP', 'NP', 'NNP', 'NNS', 'SBAR', 'WHNP', 'WDT', 'S', 'VP', 'MD', 'VP', 'VB', 'VP', 'VBN', 'ADVP', 'RB', 'PP', 'IN', 'NP', 'NNP', '.']

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

sm = SequenceMatcher(a=pos1, b=pos2)
for diff in sm.get_opcodes():
    # uncomment this to see all the diffs
    # print(diff)
    op, f1_from, f1_to, f2_from, f2_to = diff
    if op == 'equal':
        print("{}{}".format(f1_to-f1_from, tuple(pos1[f1_from:f1_to])))
```

gives:

```
5('ROOT', 'SBARQ', 'WHADVP', 'WRB', 'SQ')
1('VBP',)
3('NP', 'NNS', 'VP')
2('NP', 'NP')
6('NNS', 'SBAR', 'WHNP', 'WDT', 'S', 'VP')
2('ADVP', 'RB')
5('PP', 'IN', 'NP', 'NNP', '.')
```

Comment: It's what I want!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you reading about  [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

and here you have both examples using Recursion and Dynamic Programming both writting in python

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Python

Comment: Thanks for the information! I wonder Is there a faster way to do that, cause I have more than 300,000 sentence pairs......